# Configuring a website In IIS7, Network access issue

Tags: .net, iis-7

I have configured a website on my server machine & it is working till am accessing it on server itself but a machine in network is not able to access this.

Please help me how to make it available to all in network.

I have checked its Application pool. The application is in .net version 2.0

I have tried it with IP, Name of machine & even with port changed.

Comment: Please provide more information - what's the error, is there anything in IIS logs, system events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of message do you see in the browser when you navigate to the site?

You must open any port you are using on the Windows firewall (if it's not the default port 80).

Answer (score 2):

if you website you can see inside the server is true;

then:
Check firewall settings allow IIS Web Server ? 
Did you check IIS allow Anonymous Access ?

Answer (score 0):

If it's not the default site in the IIS you have to make it respond to some specific port or domain.

Once you do you can access by:

1. <IP>:<SelectedPort>
2. <ServerName>:<SelectedPort>

If you specified a port.

If you specified a domain in the other PC you have to add to the host file one line with the IP of the server and the domain you entered. This is the temporary solution until the domain is yours and the DNS point to your server.

Comment: no, This is what am getting : "The page cannot be displayed" when am trying to access from another machine but on server itself it is working without any issue

Comment: Can your client PC ping the server?

Comment: Yes, When I access machine yes it can but not the site. am using this <IP>:<SelectedPort>

Comment: From the server machine how are you browsing the site? <IP>:<SelectedPort>?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19761/discussion-between-neha-and-diego)